# Class load error when deploying tomcat + war container in Kubernetes

Tags: java, tomcat, kubernetes

I have an image based on tomcat jre11 with the activemq war for geoserver. I can run the image in my local docker or on my EKS cluster no problem. However when I run it on another managed Kubernetes cluster the war file fails to deploy.

I copy-pasted the full pods' log further down below... As you can see the error appears to be a class loading type of issue?

```
ERROR ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.asm.commons.EmptyVisitor can not implement org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor, because it is not an interface
```

What's really puzzling is that exact same image run perfectly fine in another k8s cluster! How is that possible?

```
    NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.006 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.20
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.009 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          May 3 2019 22:26:00 UTC
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.010 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.20.0
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.010 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.010 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.4.0-173-generic
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.010 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.010 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.010 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           11.0.3+1-Debian-1bpo91
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.010 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.010 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.010 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.019 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.019 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.019 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.019 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.020 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.020 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.020 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.020 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.020 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.020 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.020 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.020 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.020 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.21] using APR version [1.5.2].
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.020 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.020 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.024 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.0j  20 Nov 2018]
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.212 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.230 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.232 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [370] milliseconds
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.271 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.271 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.20]
20-Nov-2020 17:19:56.277 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/activemqBroker]
20-Nov-2020 17:19:58.747 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
17:19:58,840 INFO  ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
17:19:58,895 INFO  AbstractApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Nov 20 17:19:58 UTC 2020]; root of context hierarchy
17:19:58,922 ERROR ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.asm.commons.EmptyVisitor can not implement org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor, because it is not an interface (org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLo
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2415)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:863)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1186)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2415)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:863)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1186)
        at org.springframework.core.DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer.<init>(DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer.java:44)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.<init>(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:123)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.<init>(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:170)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.<init>(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.createBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:195)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:128)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:530)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:444)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:388)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4682)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5150)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1133)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1867)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:429)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
20-Nov-2020 17:19:58.924 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
20-Nov-2020 17:19:58.927 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/activemqBroker] startup failed due to previous errors
17:19:58,929 INFO  AbstractApplicationContext - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Nov 20 17:19:58 UTC 2020]; root of context hierarchy
17:19:58,929 WARN  AbstractApplicationContext - Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Nov 20 17:19:58 UTC 2020]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:340)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:327)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1037)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1000)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:554)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5388)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1133)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1867)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:429)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
17:19:58,930 WARN  AbstractApplicationContext - Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Nov 20 17:19:58 UTC 2020]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:353)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1045)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1000)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:554)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5388)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1133)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1867)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:429)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
20-Nov-2020 17:19:58.936 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/activemqBroker] has finished in [2,659] ms
20-Nov-2020 17:19:58.939 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
20-Nov-2020 17:19:58.944 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
20-Nov-2020 17:19:58.949 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [2,716] milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Spring-data is getting the old spring-asm.
You should check all dependencies with Maven’s command  `mvn dependency:tree` 
Ways of fixing it:-

> Define the Spring data dependency **AFTER** the Spring related
> dependencies. Maven transitive dependencies will fetch the correct
> Spring dependencies automatically.

According to a similar issue [here](https://mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-asm-dependency-issue-in-spring-data/)

### About java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

[Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IncompatibleClassChangeError.html)

In simple terms:-
It only happens when trying to load a class that is known to be  derived from an interface which is registered as a class. If there is no such load even if the offending class exists in the classpath their will be no exceptions. This is mainly due to the fact that java loads class if there is use for such a class in runtime or customarily by the programmer. In this case it implies that either the class in the context of the exception is either loaded customarily or used while in the other context not. This is basically the explanation.

Comment: I saw this post BUT how does it explain that it is working in one cluster and not the other? besides the war file uses spring 3.1.4

Comment: @Thomas I have edited to fully cover your question. But the recommendations should work fine despite the difference in versions.

Comment: Thanks. I hear you and I read the link you provided. The spring classes in my war are all 3.1.4, the article talks about a conflict between 3.2 and 3.1.4 which is obviously not my case here, correct or am I missing something?